# Using custom fields in a public PXSelect view in Acumatica

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a custom field in a public PXSelect view.
This is what I tried. What am I missing?

`public PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PXCache.ContractExt.usrOpportunityID, Equal<Current<CROpportunity.opportunityID>>>> Opportunity;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general structure of utilization for a custom field would be as such :

```
public PXSelect<DAC, Where<DACExtension.usrCustomField, Equal<Current<DAC2.Field>>>> View
```

If in your use case the custom field usrOpportunityID is part of the PMProject DAC the code would be as follows

```
public PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProjectExtension.usrOpportunityID, Equal<Current<CROpportunity.opportunityID>>>> Opportunity;
```